# Highcharts React update - getting a lot of lag

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm trying to update highcharts 3d options using sliders. Here's a sandbox for the same. Functionality is working as expected, however I'm observing a lot of lag. Just wanted to confirm if the method I've used for updating the chart is correct or not. Also how can I improve the performance of this snippet?

https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-highcharts-for-vibration-analysis-ccrvdc?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-column-interactive
This is what I am trying to create. But this example is in Javascript and my example is in react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors are related to bug, reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18040), as a workaround to avoid errors you can use Highcharts version under 10.2.1.

Unfortunately, the boost module doesn't work for the 3D series and there are only a few things that can slightly improve the performance. For example, we can disable markers, dataLabels, etc.

On the official [Highcharts React wrapper](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#optimal-way-to-update) you can find some examples of how to update charts.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-highcharts-for-vibration-analysis-forked-5ou63g